# Can you share any experience with FlixBus journey from Hungary to Germany?

Tags: europe, budapest, flixbus

I am an Indian traveller as well as a student to participate workshop in Hungary and Germany. So I booked for FlixBus from Budapest (Nepliget) to Germany (Essen Hbf) and its return. Both way almost 20 hours journey, ofcourse there is a connection probably at Hungary-German border. I preferred (due to financial restrictions) FlixBus because it is, at least, 50% cheaper (total 95 € for both wath way) than Flights or Train.  So I wondering if you can share your experience on the following points:

- How to identify the FlixBus at Nepliget ? Is there a fixed Bus Stop at Nepliget and Bus number ?
- I didn't book seats in advance (because it charges for prior choice). Will they automatically allot a seat during journey ?
- Since it is long journey, one needs to go washroom. Is it available within the Bus or have to wait for some intermediate stopage ?
- Is food available within the bus (provided I will pay for food) ?
- If I not forgetting any more question, the final one should be about safety for international travellers. Is it safe ?

Please share your experiences. You don't have to answer all points but whichever you will prefer.

Thanks

Comment: Despite our discussions you still went a bus? That's sad.

Comment: @chx, I am sorry but I have 3 days gap between the event in hungary and germany. So besides cheap journey I wanted to explore Europe in those 3 days. I saw train  fare was much higher. So i choosen it. Anyway thank you for your valueable suggestions

Comment: @chx can you elaborate about the discussion? Maybe it benefits others.

Comment: Did you not ask a similar question before? I dont find it. How do questions vanish from this platform, Stackexchange?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler, I asked what is the cheapest way to travel from Budapest to Eseen. That [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174627/what-is-the-cheapest-way-to-get-from-budapest-to-essen-germany?noredirect=1#comment436906_174627) was different. And chx made comment there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with Flixbus. However, almost all of your questions (save the availability of food for purchase on your specific buses) are answered on [Flixbus' FAQ webpages](https://help.flixbus.com/s/?_sp=5440da0a-27fb-4714-96ad-9739facda4f2.1656815874205&atb_pdid=e497fd25-c07c-4253-98c1-997829837ef2&language=en_IE). When you have questions, looking at the carrier's FAQ is always a good place to start.

- *Identification and Location* is discussed on the page called "[Route and Delay Information](https://help.flixbus.com/s/topic/0TO3X000000VOq3WAG/route-and-delay-information?language=en_IE)." Under "Where is my bus stop," the page says:

> **Where is my bus stop?**
>
> The address as well as a screenshot of a map with the bus stop can be found on your ticket. You can also use the navigation in our App to find it. Here's how:
> go to “Stops”
> choose the bus stop you need
> get directions on your phone by clicking the “navigation” button in the lower right corner.
> You can also find the address of any stop via Schedules & Stops.
>
> The individual bus bay for each ride can only be found at the bus stop / station (usually on the big screens).

The Flixbus webpages show pictures of Flixbuses — they're bright green.

Searching Google Maps for "Nepligent Flixbus" returns [a map showing the large bus station across the street to the southwest of the Nepligent park](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Nepliget/@47.4739332,19.0906135,15z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x4741dcdeecb5fc0d:0xf8b9a0125c1ce644!2sNepliget!8m2!3d47.4743315!4d19.0984438!3m4!1s0x4741dcdeecb5fc0d:0xf8b9a0125c1ce644!8m2!3d47.4743315!4d19.0984438).

- *Booking of Seats* is addressed on the page [Book a Ticket for your Trip](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Nepliget/@47.4739332,19.0906135,15z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x4741dcdeecb5fc0d:0xf8b9a0125c1ce644!2sNepliget!8m2!3d47.4743315!4d19.0984438!3m4!1s0x4741dcdeecb5fc0d:0xf8b9a0125c1ce644!8m2!3d47.4743315!4d19.0984438). Under "Reserving a Seat," this info is given:

> **Can I reserve seats for my trip? Where can I sit?**
>
> It goes without saying that you will always get a seat on our buses. Depending on the trip, either any place on the bus can be reserved or only certain rows. For certain buses, we do not offer seat reservations. Please check your ticket for your seat reservation.
>
> If you have not reserved a seat, but have been assigned a seat on your ticket, please sit in this seat. You will find the seat numbers in dark grey at eye level on the hand luggage compartment. If you have not reserved a seat, and have not been assigned a seat on your ticket, then you are free to choose a non-reserved seat with a green sticker. If a reservable seat is free, it could still be booked by someone later on in the trip. For this reason, please only sit on a free seat that is not reservable and is labelled with a green sticker.
>
> For a journey (consisting of two rides) with automatic connection, you will have to pay only once for the seat reservation and will get the cheaper seat reservation for free.

- *Toilet availability on the bus*

Remaining on the Booking a Ticket for your trip page, select "Preparing for your trip." This text appears:

> **How are the buses equipped?**
>
> Each bus is equipped with air conditioning, toilet, reading lights and comfortable seats. In addition, we offer free Wi-Fi, and some buses also have refreshments and snacks, sockets, USB ports and a media center for movie and music playback on request.
>
> During a trip, it is possible that the bus may travel though an area with limited reception, and as a consequence it may not be possible for all passengers to access the internet simultaneously. In rare cases, the free Wi-Fi and power outlets may not be available, for example if a replacement vehicle is in use or if we sell tickets as a sales partner.

- *Is it safe?*

This is a matter of opinion, and thus off-topic here. Still, one can observed that Flixbus is a very large business, operating in many countries. If it weren't reasonably safe for its customers, the business would fail.

Answer (score 3):

> How to identify the FlixBus at Nepliget ? Is there a fixed Bus Stop at Nepliget and Bus number ?

Already in the underpass you will see the departure board. Check your ticket for the transfer station, that's the one you need to look for. It is most likely either

1. Wien in Austria also written as Vienna in English and Bécs in Hungarian.
2. Prague in Czechia, Praha in Czech, Prága in Hungarian

You can't make a mistake, the buses have very characteristic coloring:

[image]

You are allowed to eat but please be considerate. If you get drunk and pour wine on the seat you will end up at a very different and much less comfortable destination (=I have seen police taking two people off the Vienna-Győr bus for this).

No food is being sold. Restrooms are available.

As for safety we need to consider two things:

1. The buses themselves. If you get the two decker Setra then you just hit the jackpot because at this time there's nothing more modern serving Budapest, in fact you'd be hard pressed to find anything more modern anywhere in Europe. But in general, Flixbus doesn't run Soviet era buses held together by duck tape and prayer. It's bad for business. They are modern and safe. It's the EU, after all, regulating the everliving shit out of everything is their shtick, international buses too.
2. The passengers. Well, you are riding with Hungarians. Nonetheless, this is not BKV bus 99 at 11pm. Basically, the elements of the population who would be a problem won't be able to afford a Flixbus ticket.

Overall: it's safe.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I will keep note

Comment: The buses are operated by local companies. The internet says: *FlixBus only owns one bus for licensing reasons and sources out operational execution to its driving partners* https://productmint.com/the-flixbus-business-model-how-does-flixbus-make-money/

Comment: If we want to go there: there's no such thing as flixbus. The company is called FlixMobility and contracts over 250 bus operators to operate buses under the FlixBus brand. How is this execution detail going to help OP though? The operators are not disclosed to the passengers and the quality of the buses are very tightly controlled by FlixMobility.